# Counting duplicates in an arraylist (powershell)

Tags: powershell

I have an arraylist and trying to get the number of occurrences of each value. For instance if I had [A,A,A,B,CC] then my output would be A=3, B=1, C=2

I have little experience with powershell but everything I've searched suggests using Group but my results end up with a single group of all values rather than breaking it down by duplicates like I see in examples. With example above I end up with A = 6 (the name just being the first value added to the list and count was total of all elements)

```
$list = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

$users = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $filter -SearchBase $adPath $params

$users | ForEach-Object {
    # do some logic to determine who gets added...
    $list.Add($_.office) | Out-Null
}

$list | Group
```

I also tried using a hashtable instead but I either ended up with duplicate keys (shouldn't be possible) or was saying I couldn't increment the value (key being the office, value be the count) because it was an object.

Comment: seems like just `$users | Group-Object office -NoElement` should do the trick?

Comment: What is `$users`? Show us how you populated that variable

Comment: what is `$params`  ?

Comment: @Santiago  Tried that, same result.  

I updated the code. $users is results from an ldap query

Comment: Copying to the ArrayList is entirely unnecessary. Try @SantiagoSquarzon's suggestion and pipe the `$users` array directly to `Group-Object`

Comment: assuming `$params` is something like `@{ properties = 'office' }` then you should splat it `@params`, that might be why your code is failing

Comment: It's necessary but that's my fault for not stating it. For simplicity I removed the additional logic that determined who was added to the list, because it's not the entire user base.

Comment: @Phaelaxz I understand that, but you still don't need an ArrayList. `$users = Get-ADUser ... |Where-Object { <# do your filtering here #>}`

Comment: I casted $_.office to String as its inserted and that seemed to fix the problem. I incorrectly assumed the values were already strings.

Comment: By the way ArrayLists are deprecated. Use a list with `[System.Collections.Generic.List[psobject]]::New()` instead, it has the same methods AND its `.Add()` doesn't return anything so you can remove the piping to `Out-Null`.